# Anti dll Injection with API Hooking "Access Violation writing location 0x0000000000"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, api-hook

I'm using the JMP instruction tecnique for try make a Anti-Dll Injection with detour when *LdrLoadDll* api is called inside my program. I found a Delphi code that works perfectly, but this VC++ 2013 version for this code, crashes with a

> "Access Violation writing location 0x0000000000"

with showed below.

So, how I can solve this trouble? Someone can help me please?

Thanks in advance.

**Delphi version:**

```
procedure hook(target, newfunc:pointer); 
var 
  jmpto:dword; 
    OldProtect: Cardinal; // old protect in memory 
begin 
  jmpto:=dword(newfunc)-dword(target)-5; 
  VirtualProtect(target, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @OldProtect); 
  pbyte(target)^:=$e9; 
  pdword(dword(target)+1)^:=jmpto; 
end; 

procedure myLdrLoadDll(PathToFile:PAnsiChar; Flags:variant; ModuleFileName:PAnsiChar; var ModuleHandle:THandle); 
begin 
  MessageBox(0, 'I have blocked your attempt to inject a dll file!!', 'WARNING!', MB_OK); 
  ModuleHandle:=0; 
end; 

procedure Main; 
begin 
Hook(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('ntdll.dll'), 'LdrLoadDll'), @myLdrLoadDll); 
end; 

begin 
end.
```

***Trying translate for VC++ 2013 version:***

```
 BOOL TrampolineAPI(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR DllName, LPCSTR ProcName, DWORD dwReplaced)
    {
        DWORD dwReturn;
        DWORD dwOldProtect;
        DWORD dwAddressToHook = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(DllName), ProcName);
        BYTE *pbTargetCode = (BYTE *)dwAddressToHook;
        BYTE *pbReplaced = (BYTE *)dwReplaced;
        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)dwAddressToHook, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);
        *pbTargetCode++ = 0xE9;   // My trouble is here
        *((signed int*)(pbTargetCode)) = pbReplaced - (pbTargetCode + 4);
        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)dwAddressToHook, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE, &dwOldProtect);
        dwReturn = dwAddressToHook + 5;
        FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, NULL);
        return TRUE;
    }

    void WINAPI Replaced(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
    {
        printf("Invasion!!");
    }



    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        while (true)
        {
 TrampolineAPI(GetModuleHandle(0), (LPCWSTR)"ntdll.DLL","LdrLoadDLL"(DWORD)Replaced);


        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Check the return values!! Its likely one of the many calls you're making fails but you just continue blindly on. _Find_ out which one is failing, then _find_ out how to get the error for that function then _find_ out what you could be doing wrong to get that error.

Comment: 1. Have you stepped through with a debugger? 2. I think you have some problems mixing unicode and ansi strings.

Comment: @E.Moffat, you can be right, [here](http://i.imgur.com/7EkeZfX.png) is debugger result. `DllName` variable is getting with strange characters. How solve?

Comment: I'll post as an answer so I can better explain it, but I am not sure if it is your only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem you are having is a mix between ANSI and Unicode strings.

In Win32, there are two types of encodings you'll find - Unicode (2-byte characters) and ANSI (1-byte characters). String types you'll encounter for ANSI are `LPSTR`, `LPCSTR`, etc. Wide character Unicode types are `LPWSTR`, `LPCWSTR`, etc.

There are also two types of functions in Win32 - for instance, `GetModuleHandleA`, and `GetModuleHandleW`. The way you determine which one is used is easy:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetModuleHandle GetModuleHandleW
#else
#define GetModuleHandle GetModuleHandleA
#endif //!UNICODE
```

In your particular case, you are casting a string constant with ANSI encoding to a wide-character Unicode string. This is undefined behavior. Change `TrampolineAPI(...);` in your main function to the following:

```
TrampolineAPI(GetModuleHandle(0), L"ntdll.DLL", "LdrLoadDLL", (DWORD)Replaced);
```

The `L"ntdll.DLL"` is how you define a wide-character string constant. This also avoids the typecast.

I would also recommend using the same string encoding throughout your program. This would require you to also change the signature of TrampolineAPI to

```
BOOL TrampolineAPI(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR DllName, LPCWSTR ProcName, DWORD dwReplaced) { ... }
```

And change the call in main to

```
TrampolineAPI(GetModuleHandle(0), L"ntdll.DLL", L"LdrLoadDLL", (DWORD)Replaced);
```